# Time Complexity Of Merge Sort In Special Condition

Tags: algorithm

What would be the time complexity If I will apply merge sort on an already sorted array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia page for merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort), merge sort has both a best and worse case performance of `O(n log n)`.  Given an input of an array already sorted, merge sort would still need to go through the same sorting process as for any other array.  As a result, even for a sorted array, the running time would still be `O(n log n)`.

For the case of an already-sorted array, there are other algorithms which actually beat merge sort, e.g. insertion sort.  For insertion sort, the performance of an already sorted array is `O(n)`, i.e. linear.

Answer (score 1):

Usual merge sort still uses `O(nlogn)` for sorted data.

But there is [natural merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Natural_merge_sort) variant that provides linear complexity for sorted arrays.

Note that natural merge sort also gives `O(nlogn)` for arbitrary data, compared with isertion sort, that behaves well for sorted data but becomes quadratic in the worst case